# Rails ActiveRecord - How do I determine the owner in a polymorphic relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model that could be owned by many other models (It has many foreign keys).

I'm going to try to make a polymorphic function on this model, that will behave depending on who it's owner is.  Unfortunately I'm not sure what the active record code would be to find that out, and when I go in binding.pry the self object doesn't have any information I can tell.

So a good example would be Company and Person both have a Tax ID

When the Tax ID model is going to do something, it wants to know who it's owner is.  Makes sense?

My actual relationship is a has_many, but I doubt that is the sticking point.

Comment: Usually, in polymorphic association, you have two columns `<relation_name>_type` and `<relation_name>_id`. So I guess in your Tax table you can find these 2 columns (in your case `owner_type` and `owner_id`)

Comment: @MrYoshji - You are correct, but when doing binding.pry I look at the self object to see which parent id is set, to no avail.
I figure there's some kind of accessor to the owner that would make the code cleaner anyhow, but I can't really find it.

Comment: When you do the binding pry, look at the polymorphic column ( probably `taxable_type` ) and it should tell you the model to which it's associated.

Comment: alternatively, tax_item.taxable.class.name

Comment: If the action is dependent on the owning class, you could also consider moving the relevant method(s) to the owning class. That is, if you currently have a `tax_item#some_method`, you might want to consider moving that to `company#some_method` and `person#some_method`. The caveat here is that unless you can strongly enforce the API by allowing `Person` and `Company` to inherit from the same ancestor (which I doubt), you don't want to do this if there's more than a few `taxable_type` options (or could be) or more than a few methods that would be pushed to the owning classes.

Comment: @wmjbyatt that sounds good!  I can leave the generic at the Tax ID level, and customize it as needed at the higher level.  I will try this solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the following structure,

```
class Tax
  belongs_to :taxable, polymorphic: true
end

class Company
  has_many :taxes, as: :taxable
end

class Person
  has_many :taxes, as: :taxable
end

create_table :taxes do |t|
  t.integer :taxable_id
  t.string  :taxable_type
  t.timestamps
end
```

each tax record can access its owner using `tax.taxable`. To get the type, use either

```
tax.taxable.class.name
```

or

```
tax.taxable_type
```

(With help from @SteveTurczyn and @MrYoshiji.)

Answer (score 0):

`class Tax
    belongs_to :taxable, :polymorphic => true  # tax table needs taxable_type taxable_id
  end`

class Company
    has_one :tax, :as => :taxable
  end

class Person
    has_one :tax, :as => :taxable
  end

Tax.first.taxable

Comment: And you are right, has_one vs has_many doesn't matter.. use either